# jQuery: count input checked in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the number of machines I selected.

here we have a list of virtual machines and I would like to count the selection that is when I press an input there is the element that is checked.

i tried this but not working.

```
   $("table input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
        let nbchecked = $("table input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
        console.log(nbchecked);
        let len = nbchecked.length;

          $(".counter").html(nbchecked); //inject the number of vm checked in the div
    });
```

I am a beginner in javascript and jquery and I don't know how to do it.
I need your help plz

Comment: could you please post your html and other code

Comment: As advised in the "answer" below, the code you've provided works fine.   When you state *"it's not working"*, can you be more specific?  Does the event fire?  Do you get the console.log(nbchecked)?  Is there a `.counter` element to receive the values?   Does the table exist when your code runs - try wrapping it inside [doc.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) - or putting your code last on the page.  Are there any console errors, eg `$ is not defined`?

Comment: Please also have a read of [mcve] - ideally, if you include a *complete* snippet with *just* enough html/code/css to *recreate* / *demonstrate* the problem, then you'll likely get an answer much quicker.

Comment: I mean there is nothing in the console. look above I posted my html.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It work, post your html plz

```js
$("table input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
      let nbchecked = $("table input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
      console.log(nbchecked);
      let len = nbchecked.length;

        $(".counter").html(nbchecked); //inject the number of vm checked in the div
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="vm_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="id_vms_1">
          <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="12" id="id_vms_1"> vm1
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="id_vms_2">
          <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="13" id="id_vms_2"> vm2
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="id_vms_3">
          <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="14" id="id_vms_3"> vm3
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="counter"></div>
```